# Convert TimeZone Identifiers In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I need to convert time zone identifiers into Rails ActiveSupport compatible timezones. I am trying to assert that a time is in a given zone. The Ruby Time class gives the zone as `Time.now.zone => 'PDT'` and `DateTime.now.zone => '-07:00'` but when i try to use this identifier with TZInfo or ActiveSupport get an `Invalid Identifier: PDT` error.

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo(Time.now.zone) => Invalid Identifier: PDT
TZInfo::Timezone.get('PDT') => Invalid Identifier: PDT
```

It seems very weird that the Ruby Time and DateTime zone identifiers wouldn't be easily convertible between themselves and Rails helpers. I could use the utc_offset method, but that's a bit problematic bc I don't have a mapping to named zones that way.

Comment: Note that PDT (Pacific Daylight Time) has an UTC offset of -07:00, not +09:00.

Comment: Right, +9 is Tokyo, I was playing with different zones. I will update it for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems very weird that the Ruby Time and DateTime zone identifiers wouldn't be easily convertible between themselves and Rails helpers

It is not weird, it is kinda *expected* (and not specific to Ruby, taking into account how convoluted the time[zones] topic is).

Rails is a very opinionated framework, and with regards to timezones it goes completely different way: while Ruby's timezones implementation [follows RFC2822](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/time.rb#L31), `TZInfo` is based on  [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) which is quite different beast serving different purposes.

In general, there are many problems with the time zone abbreviations (like PDT one) - they are ambiguous and at best represent an offset, not a timezone per se (there are more probles that these ones - take a look at [this detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)).

So, I'd say the rule of thumb is that you either use Ruby's minimalistic built-in timezone support, or Rails' extended one  (that comes with `TZInfo`), but not both.

WRT your particular task (that I'm not fully undertstanding, honeslty) - there are separate gems (like `TimezoneParser`, but maybe there is something "more alive") that could probably help you with this mapping.